# Unequal breaks and label lengths error when alpha (transparency) level not present in data

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2 version 2.2.0, E.g.:

```
tmp_df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, alpha = rep(0.5, 3))

#   x y alpha
# 1 1 1   0.5
# 2 2 2   0.5
# 3 3 3   0.5

ggplot(tmp_df, aes(x, y, alpha = alpha)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    scale_alpha(breaks = c(0.25, 0.5, 1), labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Produces the error:

```
Error in f(..., self = self) : Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

Manually removing the extra alpha values in `scale_alpha` fixes the problem, but surely this can be handled some how by ggplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must supply the limits for the scale because `tmp_df$alpha` is always the same, and `ggplot` does not know the 'range' of the scale.

```r
library(ggplot2)
tmp_df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, alpha = rep(0.5, 3))
tmp_df
#>   x y alpha
#> 1 1 1   0.5
#> 2 2 2   0.5
#> 3 3 3   0.5

ggplot(tmp_df, aes(x, y, alpha = alpha)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    scale_alpha(breaks = c(0.25, 0.5, 1), labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'), limits = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

If the `alpha` dimension has a range itself, limits are no longer necessary, but note the in the following example the first `break` is ignored, as it is outside the range. `limits` would again be necessary if you want to include it.

```r
tmp_df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3, alpha = seq(.5, 1.5, .5))
tmp_df
#>   x y alpha
#> 1 1 1   0.5
#> 2 2 2   1.0
#> 3 3 3   1.5

ggplot(tmp_df, aes(x, y, alpha = alpha)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    scale_alpha(breaks = c(0.25, 0.5, 1), labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

[image]