# How to get consistent transparency (alpha) across plots in ggplot2 (ver 2.2.0)

Tags: r, ggplot2

E.g.

```
tmp_df <-
    expand.grid(group = 1:2, x = 1:3)

tmp_df$y <- 1:6
tmp_df$alpha <- c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.75, 0.1, 1)

p1 <- ggplot(tmp_df, aes(x, y, alpha = alpha)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    facet_grid(group ~ .)

tmp_df2 <- tmp_df
tmp_df2$alpha <- 0.1

p2 <- ggplot(tmp_df2, aes(x, y, alpha = alpha)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    facet_grid(group ~ .)
```

So that:

```
> tmp_df
  group x y alpha
1     1 1 1  0.10
2     2 1 2  0.10
3     1 2 3  0.10
4     2 2 4  0.75
5     1 3 5  0.10
6     2 3 6  1.00

> tmp_df2
  group x y alpha
1     1 1 1   0.1
2     2 1 2   0.1
3     1 2 3   0.1
4     2 2 4   0.1
5     1 3 5   0.1
6     2 3 6   0.1
```

Now consider:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

which produces the following plot (p1 is on left, p2 on right):

[image]

We see that while `ggplot` has no problems rendering alpha levels consistent (specifically the 0.1 level) within a facetted plot, making two plots with differing levels of `alpha` in the data seems to lead to a inconsistent result. I.e. right hand bars are much much darker than expected. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is closely related to my previous question, and the answer is given by specifying the scale limit as per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43250030/2109289

Specifically, passing limits to both plots fixes the problem:

```
p1 <- ggplot(tmp_df, aes(x, y, alpha = alpha)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    scale_alpha(limits = c(0, 1)) +
    facet_grid(group ~ .)

p2 <- ggplot(tmp_df2, aes(x, y, alpha = alpha)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
    scale_alpha(limits = c(0, 1)) +
    facet_grid(group ~ .)
```